# How to set default argument with self in python def?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to call the `__init__` variable as a default variable but it is not calling

```
class test1:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def method1(self,name2=self.name):
        return name2
```

If I call the function like

```
from test import test1
ma = test1("mkHun")

va = ma.method1() # Here I am expected output is mkhun

ca = ma.method1("new name")
```

In JavaScript this features is called as [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). Is this features is available in python or something problem with my code?

Comment: You cannot use self as a default parameter because it is not defined unlike javascript. or if you like, you can use None as a default parameter then check it in code, i know it would be good if the default parameter can use self but not.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to achieve similar functionality. Others may have a more pythonic way. Code inspired by the [docs here](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html)

```
class test1:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def method1(self, newName=None): 
        if newName is not None:
            self.name = newName
        return self.name


ma = test1("mkHun")

va = ma.method1() # Here I am expected output is mkhun
print(va)

ca = ma.method1("new name")
print(ca)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class test1:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def method1(self, name2="This would work"):
        """You can already use self.name here without taking it from the method argument
        since self.name always exists, you don't need to put it in the method arguments"""
        return name2


ma = test1("mkHun")

va = ma.method1() # Here I am expected output is mkhun

ca = ma.method1("new name")

print(ma.name, "--->", va,"--->", ca)
```

self.variable is in reach for every method you define inside the class but @staticmethod, so you can simply give it a `None` as default argument and inside your method if the argument is None use the `self.name` and if it is not None and the argument indeed exist, use it instead. Hope it helps.